# When running Tableau against BigQuery, there is no Query History

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

When running a report on the Tableau Cloud against BigQuery, there is no Query History.
Even when I refresh the datasource with a new day of data, and I see that the report now shows the new date, there is no Query History.  I need to see the History to calculate costs and to understand what Tableau is doing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to use same user for tableau and for retrieving query history

Comment: Thanks!  That's crazy that the administrator would not be able to see all of the queries.  Queries have a cost and only the query history tells me who is creating what costs.  The admin has to know what costs are being incurred by who!  Oh well I'll complain to Google  :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a flag administrators can use on the jobs API to retrieve jobs for all users in the project they administer. See the allUsers flag described at:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list

This functionality is not available in the UI but you can use the command line tool (bq) to retrieve jobs across users. It has a flag that enables this option.

Comment: Thanks. Jobs includes any queries that they run in the UI?

Comment: Yes, each query is associated with a job.